# How delete indentation in a cell tabular - Latex

Tags: latex, tabular

I would like to remove the indentation from the item bullet but I can't. I tried with the code :

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
```

for each itemize, but here happens

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    %\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{| m{2.5cm} | m{5cm} | m{5cm} |}
        \hline
        Types of maintenance & Pros & Cons \\
        \hline
        Curative maintenance & 
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] 
            \item[$\bullet$] Minimal staff needed. 
            \item[$\bullet$] Minimal planning required.
         \end{itemize}   
         & 
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] 
            \item[$\bullet$] Extremely costly.
            \item[$\bullet$] Safety risk for employers. 
            \item[$\bullet$] Unpredictable failures 
        \end{itemize} 
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

otherwise without leftmargin i get this but i really wish there was no indentation of the bullets please and how can I put "pros" and "cons" in the middle?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]` is non-standard syntax. You have to load the `enumitem` package if you want to use this syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    %\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.1cm}
    \begin{tabular}{| m{2.5cm} | m{5cm} | m{5cm} |}
        \hline
        Types of maintenance & Pros & Cons \\
        \hline
        Curative maintenance & 
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] 
            \item[$\bullet$] Minimal staff needed. 
            \item[$\bullet$] Minimal planning required.
         \end{itemize}   
         & 
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] 
            \item[$\bullet$] Extremely costly.
            \item[$\bullet$] Safety risk for employers. 
            \item[$\bullet$] Unpredictable failures 
        \end{itemize} 
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]